# How to vertical align element in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertical align some elements in my div and for some reason it doesn't work

I have something like

html

```
<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="test1.png"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="test2.png"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:middle
}

.test img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Basically my images height is different but i want everything inside the test div to be vertically aligned no matter what the images height is. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to set test class height and then add to .test img `display: block;` - blah, disregard

Comment: This type of thing is far more difficult than it should be. Basically, your easy options come down to using tables or using JavaScript to align your content. There are CSS options as well, but they are not nearly as straightforward.

Comment: @Andy What? lol, of course you can vertically align elements using CSS and it's not hard, working on it.

Comment: @odedta - I didn't say it was hard... I said it was harder _than it should be_. It's getting better with CSS3, but if you want something that's backward compatible, you're looking at some pretty nasty looking stuff.

Comment: Well, the answers people posted here are backwards-compatible and are pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution may not cover all instances but setting the `line-height` will get the vertical alignment that you're looking for. Swap out `height` for `line-height`.

```html
<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/30x30"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>
```

```css
.test {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px;        
}
.test img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hq1akdo6/

The major caveat to this approach is that it doesn't work for multi-line text.

Answer (score 1):

in the vertical-align property. This excellent article explains it:

Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content" 
Inline elements (and only inline elements) can be vertically aligned in their context via vertical-align: middle. However, the “context” isn’t the whole parent container height, it’s the height of the text line they’re in. jsfiddle example

For block elements, vertical alignment is harder and strongly depends on the specific situation:
If the inner element can have a fixed height, you can make its position absolute and specify its height, margin-top and top position. jsfiddle example
If the centered element consists of a single line and its parent height is fixed you can simply set the container’s line-height to fill its height. This method is quite versatile in my experience. jsfiddle example
… there are be more such special cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

CSS :

```
.test{
    float:left;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="test.png"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="test1.png"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <a href="#"><img src="test2.png"/></a>
    <a href="#">Text here...</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this is what you are looking for check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xd495yef/)

```
    .test{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        margin:10px;
        text-align: center;
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

    .test a {
        display:block;
    }
```

The key here being

```
  display:table-cell
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if the images are different heights like the question suggests. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeanpierreb/d4sztLgh/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="300" height="300">
  <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>

<style>
figcaption {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: He has an image and a text that is vertically aligned below, he can set the `margin-top` and that way get the text to always be where he wants it to be relative to the container.

Comment: Thanks odedta, but your solution set the height to 300 for all images. My images have different height. I might take hungerstar's solution. Thanks!

Comment: You can set the height to whatever you like... sure.

Comment: I mean, the images I put in have height like 300px or 400px so I can't set an universal height.

Comment: I think the OP wants the layout to have the image inline with the text. This solution places the text below the image.

Comment: Yes, but how can you vertically align a text when you don't know the height of the container lol, everything is relative, what is the vertical-align relative to? :)